# Add image to the JSP page in JavaMailSender

Tags: java, spring, image, jsp, email

I have an application which send emails to users. Emails are stored in database and all of them are JSP pages. Everything works fine, but now I want add an image to the JSP. Not as an attachment, just as a `<img src="..."></img>`.

I am using Spring Boot and all images I keep in resources/img directory, but when I do something like this in mail template:

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <img src="/resources/img/logo.png"></img>               
    </div>  
</div>
```

and send mail, this image do not show in my account. I'm also using gmail smtp and send all emails to the gmail. Where is a problem?
Is it connect to the security between my application and gmail server? Or maybe I should try to keep all images in database, not in separate directory?

Answer (score 0):

The image URL must be an absolute URL pointing to your server and allow to fetch the image over the web. For example:

```
<img src="http://server.with.the.image/img/logo.png"></img>
```

The URL must work if you test it with a browser.

Comment: can you give an example and tell more about fetching it?

Comment: Ok, I have an URL like http://localhost:8080/img/logo.png but it doesn't work. My application is a REST service, so in back response I get {"timestamp":1444494412768,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/img/logo.png"} I don't think I should return this image byapi?

Comment: My mistake - gmail cannot read localhost. What if want add this image as an attachment? Is it possible?